# Ghostscript - Indentation of postscript code

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

Is there an option for to me to ask Ghostscript to indent the Postscript it creates?

Everything starts at the beginning of a line and I find it difficult to follow.

Alternatively, I am using Emacs and ps-mode.

If anyone know how to indent code in this mode I would appreciate a tip (apologize because this may not be relevant to this StackExchange)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no option for indenting the output.

PostScript is pretty much regarded as a write-only language anyway, and the output of ps2write (which is what I assume you are using though you don't say) is particularly difficult since it fundamentally outputs PDF syntax with a PostScript program on the front to parse it into PostScript operations.

Why do you want to read it ?

[EDIT]

You can always edit your question, you don't need to post a new answer.

I'm afraid what you want to do isn't as simple as you might think.

It **might** be possible for this use case if the PDF files you receive are always created the same way, but there are significant problems.

The font you use as a substitute for the missing font must be encoded the same way. Say for example the font in the PDF file is encoded so that 0x41 is 'A', you need to make sure that the replacement font is also encoded so that 0x41 is an 'A'. So just the findfont, scalefont, setfont sequence is not always going to be sufficient, sometimes you will need to re-encode the font.

CIDFonts will be a major stumbling block. Firstly because ps2write simply doesn't emit CIDFonts at all. These were not part of level 2 PostScript. As a result all text in a CIDFont will be embedded as bitmaps. If your original file doesn't contain the CIDFont then you'll get the fallback CIDFont bitmapped.

Secondly CIDFonts can use multiple-byte character codes, of variable length. You can't simply replace a CIDFont with a Font, it just won't work.

The best solution, obviously, is to have the PDF files created with the fonts required embedded. This is best practice. If you can't get that, then I'd suggest that rather than trying to hand edit PostScript, you use the fontmap.GS and cidfmap files which Ghostscript uses to find font.

Ghostscript already has a load of code to do font substitution automatically, using both Fonts and CIDFonts as substitutes, and it does all the hard work of re-encoding the fonts or building CMaps as required. If you are on Windows much of this may already be done for you, when you install Ghostscript it will ask if you want to create font mappings. If you said yes then it will

Add the font substitutions you want to use in those files (they have comments explaining the layout) and then use the **pdfwrite** device to make a new PDF file. Set `EmbedAllFonts` to true (you may need to add a `AlwayEmbed` font array as well, listing the fonts specifically) and `SubsetFonts` to false.

That should create a new PDF file where the missing fonts have been replaced by your defined substitutes, those substitutes will have been embedded in the new PDF file and they have will not been subset (Acrobat will generally refuse to edit text in a subset font).

The switches I mentioned above are standard Adobe Distiller parameters, but they are documented for pdfwrite [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.52/VectorDevices.htm#COMMON). There's some documentation on adding fonts [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.52/Fonts.htm#Add_fonts) and [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.52/Fonts.htm#About) and specifically for CIDFonts [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.52/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution).

Basically I'd suggest you define your substitutions and let Ghostscript do the work for you.

Comment: See the answer below. The comment field is too short for me to answer your question "Why do you want to read it?"

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the problem but rather an answer to KenS's question about "Why do you want to read it?"

I tried to put it in the comment box but it was too long.

I am a retired engineer with a strong programming background.

I would like to read and understand the postscript code for the reason shown below.

I play duplicate bridge as a hobby. I recieve a PDF file of what is know as a convention card (a single page document of bridge agreements).

Frequently I would like to edit these files.

When I open with Adobe Illustrator I have to spend a significant amount of time replacing fonts that are not on my system with fonts that I do have.

I can take the PDF and export it as a postscript file using Ghostscript.

I was going to write a little program to replace the embedded fonts with the fonts that I use to replace them.

I was going to leave the postscript file unaltered and insert things like

```
  /HelveticaMonospacedPro-RG findfont
  12 scalefont setfont
```

just above where the text is written.

I was planning on using the fonts that I have on my system (e.g., HelveticaMonospacedPro-RG).